# NullPointerException with Simple HTMLserializer

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing, htmlcleaner

I am trying to parse html from a `TagNode`.
The problem is, there is an inner exception prevents it from working.
Here is my call:

```
CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();
SimpleHtmlSerializer serializer = new SimpleHtmlSerializer(props);
changes.setHtmlForTimetable(serializer.getAsString(root));
```

root of course is not null, and obviously serializer is not null also.

This is the stack trace:

```
01-21 23:42:50.860: W/System.err(25196): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 23:42:50.865: W/System.err(25196):    at org.htmlcleaner.HtmlSerializer.isMinimizedTagSyntax(HtmlSerializer.java:54)
01-21 23:42:50.875: W/System.err(25196):    at org.htmlcleaner.HtmlSerializer.serializeOpenTag(HtmlSerializer.java:189)
01-21 23:42:50.880: W/System.err(25196):    at org.htmlcleaner.SimpleHtmlSerializer.serialize(SimpleHtmlSerializer.java:52)
01-21 23:42:50.885: W/System.err(25196):    at org.htmlcleaner.Serializer.write(Serializer.java:249)
01-21 23:42:50.890: W/System.err(25196):    at org.htmlcleaner.Serializer.getAsString(Serializer.java:176)
01-21 23:42:50.900: W/System.err(25196):    at org.htmlcleaner.Serializer.getAsString(Serializer.java:197)
01-21 23:42:50.905: W/System.err(25196):    at org.htmlcleaner.Serializer.getAsString(Serializer.java:206)
01-21 23:42:50.915: W/System.err(25196):    at com.roneven.blich.GetChanges$1$1$1.callback(GetChanges.java:125)
01-21 23:42:50.920: W/System.err(25196):    at com.roneven.blich.GetChanges$1$1$1.callback(GetChanges.java:1)
01-21 23:42:50.930: W/System.err(25196):    at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.callback(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:501)
01-21 23:42:50.935: W/System.err(25196):    at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.afterWork(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:1269)
01-21 23:42:50.940: W/System.err(25196):    at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.run(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:993)
01-21 23:42:50.945: W/System.err(25196):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-21 23:42:50.945: W/System.err(25196):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 23:42:50.950: W/System.err(25196):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 23:42:50.950: W/System.err(25196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
01-21 23:42:50.955: W/System.err(25196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 23:42:50.955: W/System.err(25196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 23:42:50.960: W/System.err(25196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-21 23:42:50.960: W/System.err(25196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-21 23:42:50.965: W/System.err(25196):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPDATE:
I found a workaround, without even using HtmlSerializer or TagNode (using html I already extracted successfully and some string commands)

Comment: It is a `TagNode` object. and it is not null

Comment: changes is also not null. You can see that in the stack trace the exception is thrown INSIDE the `HtmlSerializer`. so this is probably not the problem. Maybe somehow it can be related that it is a static method?

Comment: I saw that changes wasn't null after and edited. I'm thinking that maybe root contains something null. Maybe posting more code would help and also how you call your method.

Comment: Thanks, but I found a workaround, without even using HtmlSerializer or TagNode (using html I already extracted successfully and some string commands)

Answer (score 1):

According to sources from [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net), `HtmlSerializer.isMinimizedTagSyntax()` calls `CleanerProperties.getTagInfoProvider()`. And in `CleanerProperties.java`

```
ITagInfoProvider tagInfoProvider = null;
...
public ITagInfoProvider getTagInfoProvider() {
    return tagInfoProvider;
}
```

There's no method to set it in `CleanerProperties`. `tagInfoProvider` must be set somehow, before you use it.

I think, to find out how, you must dig a bit into HtmlCleaner's documentation, which is available at [Java code usage](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php) for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I found a workaround, without even using HtmlSerializer or TagNode (using html I already extracted successfully and some string commands)

Answer (score 0):

I have just the same problem and spent quite a lot of time finding solution.

```
CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties() {

    @Override
    public ITagInfoProvider getTagInfoProvider() {
        return DefaultTagProvider.getInstance();
    }

};

HtmlSerializer simpleHtmlSerializer = new SimpleHtmlSerializer(props);
String message = simpleHtmlSerializer.getAsString(tagNode, true);
```